# Whether Jest is used only for unit testing the React Js code or it can be used to UI Test the React Js application?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, jestjs

I've got a Test Automation requirement for the React JS application. Its a Retail Web based application, I Would like to know whether jest can be used for Automating the UI of the reactjs application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a application is unit tested it actually not deployed or running. It usually build phase of application when unit testing is done before deployment. So how an application can be tested ? It is the JEST which runs your react code for unit testing or you can say it what mount you components so that you can run unit test on those components.

**So its a unit testing api from airbnb.com.**

If you are looking for selenium kind of alternative you can use Protractor for react app which is widely used.

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit testing as well as integration test with Jest. also, you can configure an enzyme library for shallow dom testing, snapshot testing and many more. There are a lot of benefits to jest beyond testing.